# QObject преобразование типов

Tags: qt, qt5

Добрый день! 
Помогите разобратся со строчкой! из Qt Example. Идет преобразование типов, но не пойму на что ссылается. Строчка из примеров Qt modbus Tcp.

```
auto reply = qobject_cast<QModbusReply *>(sender());
```

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qmodbusreply.html

Answer (score 2):

`qobject_cast` служит для преобразования типов, наследуемых от `QObject` без использования RTTI. Работает аналогично `dynamic_cast` и с аналогичным синтаксисом.

Данная строчка вызывается в слоте, присоединенном к сигналу. Вызывается функция `sender()`, возвращающая указатель на объект, отправивший сигнал. Вернувшийся указатель приводится к типу `QModbusReply` с помощью вышеупомянутого `qobject_cast`.